# Facebook comments / permanent link

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I had setup my website to use Facebook comments (using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) and was all working fine.

Unfortunately, my domain name expired and was snapped up by a domain parking company before I renewed it.  I purchased a new domain name (the same, but .net instead of .com) and setup the website.

I have put in the same code as the previous site, and the comments do appear (because the old url is in the code), but on facebook profiles, the links are broken because they point to the old site (.com).

I can swap every .com for .net in the facebook code to get the links in Facebook working again, but this will mean I loose all my comments.

I would like to know if there is anyway of asking Facebook to move the comments associated with the old URLs to the new URLs, because I guess this is the only way of keeping my comments and making the links in facebook.com work (linking back to my new site).

Any info appreciated, I know this may not be a coding issue but it seems to be the best place to ask.  I have seen similar posts, but they still have access to their old pages.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can retrieve the comments made on your old domain, but you will not be able to import them as regular Facebook comments.

Instead, you can use a tool like [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com/), to export the comments you retrieve from Facebook.

To retrieve the comments, use one of the following methods:

1. Using Facebook Graph API

   ```
    https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={YOUR_OLD_DOMAIN_URL}
   ```
2. Using [Facebook FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/)

Then, use [this post](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/715797-can-i-import-comments-from-facebook-comments-) to help you exporting the comments to Disqus.